H2 database columns and values don't converge Spring Boot
I'm trying to insert data into a table named "movie" using Spring Boot and H2 database. However, the columns and values don't converge. I've tried using the INSERT INTO statement, but it doesn't seem to match exactly what i'm doing.
`                package com.example.movieapi.movieapi.movies;
            import com.example.movieapi.movieapi.reviews.Review;
            import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
            import jakarta.persistence.*;
            import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
            
            import java.util.List;
            
            @Entity
            public class Movie {
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private Long id;
                private String name;
            
                private String releasedate;
                private String image;
                private String trailer;
                private String backdrops;
                @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie")
                @JsonIgnore
                private List<Review> reviews;
            
                public Long getId() {
                    return id;
                }
            
                public void setId(Long id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }
            
                public String getName() {
                    return name;
                }
            
                public void setName(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
                }
            
                public String getReleasedate() {
                    return releasedate;
                }
            
                public void setReleasedate(String releasedate) {
                    this.releasedate = releasedate;
                }
            
                public String getImage() {
                    return image;
                }
            
                public void setImage(String image) {
                    this.image = image;
                }
            
                public String getTrailer() {
                    return trailer;
                }
            
                public void setTrailer(String trailer) {
                    this.trailer = trailer;
                }
            
                public String getBackdrops() {
                    return backdrops;
                }
            
                public void setBackdrops(String backdrops) {
                    this.backdrops = backdrops;
                }
            
                public List<Review> getReviews() {
                    return reviews;
                }
            
                public void setReviews(List<Review> reviews) {
                    this.reviews = reviews;
                }
            
                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return "Movie{" +
                            "ID=" + id +
                            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                            ", releaseDate='" + releasedate + '\'' +
                            ", image='" + image + '\'' +
                            ", trailer='" + trailer + '\'' +
                            ", backDrops='" + backdrops + '\'' +
                            '}';
                }
            }

`
what i put:
INSERT INTO Movie
(id, name, releasedate, image, trailer, backdrops)
VALUES
(1001, 'Spider-Man: No Way Home', '2021', 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWMyYzFjYTYtNTRjYi00OGExLWE2YzgtOGRmYjAxZTU3NzBiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzQ0MzA0NTM@.V1_FMjpg_UX1000.jpg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnFDOzyGDsM', 'https://4kwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/spider-man-no-way-home-2021-movies-marvel-comics-3440x1440-6992.jpg');
and what i got


I can't understand your problem, please explain what you expect to get instead of the current outcome. Also, why are you using native SQL for a standard JPA entity?

i'm adding content manually but it seems the database doesn't match the order for exemple i add the content for the order: (id, name, releasedate, image, trailer, backdrops) but it showed in h2 database in this order :
(ID   BACKDROPS   IMAGE   NAME   RELEASEDATE   TRAILER)

Inserting into a table is nothing more than mapping record entries to its fields, regardless of the order you initially did within the command parameters. From a programmatically point of view it doesn't matter at all, since all you wanna get is data out of the database. And if you search the db with a client tool you do the ordering and grouping as desired anyway. Anyhow, you might wanna have a look at the script doing the table creation and rearrange the columns in your interest.

still facing the same problem in mysql
